# how do I exists the telepresence intercep

Tags: macos, telepresence

I am using this command to intercep the service:

```
telepresence intercept chat-server-service --port 8002:8002 --env-file ./env
```

how do I terminate the intercept safety? I check the intercept command:

```
telepresence intercept --help
```

did not found the exists command. I also tried to kill the process but could not found which process should I kill:

```
> ps aux|grep intercept
xiaoqiangjiang   30747   0.0  0.0 408626880   1312 s009  S+    1:48PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox intercept
> ps aux|grep telepresence
xiaoqiangjiang   78916   0.3  0.3 413777600  88416   ??  S    Tue12PM   9:46.96 /opt/homebrew/bin/telepresence connector-foreground
root             78937   0.1  0.2 413599888  81328   ??  S    Tue12PM   6:10.95 /opt/homebrew/bin/telepresence daemon-foreground /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Logs/telepresence /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/telepresence
xiaoqiangjiang   49214   0.0  0.0 408627424    336 s008  S+   11:07PM   0:00.01 bash ./macbook-backup-full-reddwarf-dolphin-telepresence.sh
root             78936   0.0  0.0 408646448   2848   ??  S    Tue12PM   0:00.01 sudo --non-interactive /opt/homebrew/bin/telepresence daemon-foreground /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Logs/telepresence /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Application Support/telepresence
xiaoqiangjiang   30771   0.0  0.0 408626880   1312 s009  S+    1:48PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox telepresence
```

what should I do to terminal the telepresence process safety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to terminate intercept you need to run

`telepresence  leave` - (Remove existing intercept)

for example:

`telepresence intercept notifications --port 8080`

`telepresence leave notifications`

Comment: why the `telepresence intercept --help ` did not mention this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `telepresence intercept --help` doesn't mention the `telepresence leave` command. But if you run `telepresence --help`, you'll see `telepresence leave` on the list.

We try to match the `--help` flag to the specified parameters - so since there's no command like `telepresence intercept leave` it's not going to show up under the `telepresence intercept --help` results. So whenever you don't see a flag you are looking for try running the `telepresence --help` command instead.